# Using Parse Client Key in Angular gives CORS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, cors

I am attempting to retrieve a class (with GET) from Parse using a client key. I was able to send a successful request using Advanced Rest Client for Google Chrome; I used `X-Parse-Application-Id` and `X-Parse-Client-Key` headers.

[edit] [edit2]
Response headers (obtained from Chrome Developer Tools OPTIONS):

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Date: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 04:23:08 GMT
>
> Server: nginx/1.6.0
>
> X-Parse-Platform: G1
>
> X-Runtime: 0.000118
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Connection: keep-alive

However, attempting to do the same in an Angular app gives me the following error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GenResources. Request header field X-Parse-Client-Key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Parse says it supports using [cross-origin resource sharing](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#quick-reference-request-format), and I was able to make the request earlier using a different client so I'm pretty sure the server isn't the issue. I wouldn't be able to modify what the response header is anyways.

Here's the code I used to form the GET request.

```
var ng_portal = angular.module("ngPortal", []);
ng_portal.controller("GenResourcesCtrl", ["$http", function($http) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: PARSE_URL + "/1/classes/GenResources",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_APP_ID,
      "X-Parse-Client-Key": PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
    }
  }).then(
    function success(res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
    function error(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  );
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting custom headers in the request, which will trigger a pre-flight (OPTIONS) request.  The response from that request must include a header called "access-control-allow-headers" with the value being a list of the headers you are trying to set.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

specifically the section on pre-flight requests.

I suggest using the browser developer tools to look at the headers of the requests and responses to see if they conform to the CORS spec.  From the error message you provided, it looks like the server hosting the cross domain call you are making, does not support custom headers.  If you see otherwise, please update your question with the headers and I can provide more help.

Comment: As stated in the API documents at https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#quick-reference-request-format, Parse supports cross-origin resource sharing and I was able to retrieve a successful response with the data I requested from it.

I will update the original question with the headers. The response headers do contain *Access-Control-Allow-Methods* and *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*, but not the one you mentioned...

Comment: Please disable caching in Chrome developer tools, and right click on reload, then select to hard clear the cache and reload.  You should see a new OPTIONS call prior to the primary request in the network tab.  Please update the question with the headers of that pre-flight OPTIONS call.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to check my response headers. I can now see the allowed headers do not contain a `X-Parse-Client-Key` unlike what the documentation said. There is still the issue that the Advanced REST client is working and retrieving data, but I might be able to discern the problem at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Parse.com actually. After exactly one frustrated hour, I came across [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/HDHMrVW2xGU)

Relevant quote

> From my testing, this never ( client or javascript key) worked via javascript rest interactions through the browser.
>
> I actually created a Parse Bug on this:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/488204124680438
>
> Because I thought both of those keys should work through the browser ( WITHOUT NEEDING TO USE A SDK ).
>
> I’d suggest reading reading my bug.  I still think the the correct implementation is to enable these keys to work properly with browser requests because it works if you do it outside the browser.
>
> But alas, they don’t seem to get the issue, or don’t understand why disabling it only in the browser doesn’t make sense since you can use it on any other platform without issues. Just… Doesn’t… Make… Sense.

I instead used my JavaScript Key `X-Parse-Javascript-Key` (which, according to the docs as of today, only works with their JavaScript SDK) and it works fine as a drop-in replacement for `X-Parse-Client-Key`